# How to replicate Microsoft Teams Channel UI with fluentUI?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui

I would like to replicate the UI for a channel in a team for Microsoft Teams. The `@fluentui/react-northstar` package has the `chat` component https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/components/chat/definition but it differs to a channel message.

Are there components to recreate this, or do I have to manipulate the styling of the `chat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a prototype available at [ThreadedMessage.tsx](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/fluentui/docs/src/prototypes/chatMessages/ThreadedMessages/ThreadedMessage.tsx) which you can follow. It shows how to adopt the look and feel of a ChatMessage component to the threaded model.